# Checking pointer address and value from a function

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm a beginner to C and have been reading a book called "Understanding and Using C Pointers" and ended up running into a problem with using the printf function.

When using debug_p, it turns out that the address of the pointer num_p is different but exact to num in debug, but it returns the correct value when attempting a printf within main().

My question is, why is this so? Is there an appropriate way to do a printf within a function and have a correct address of a pointer?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void debug(int num)
{
    printf("Address of num: %i Value: %i\n", &num, num);
}

void debug_p(int *num_p)
{
    printf("Address of num_p: %i Value %i\n", &num_p, num_p);

}


int main()
{
int num=11;
int *num_p=&num;
printf("Address of num: %i Value: %i\n", &num, num);
printf("Address of num_p: %i Value: %i\n\n", &num_p, num_p);

debug(num);
debug_p(num_p);
return 0;
}
```

---

Output from main():

```
Address of num: 2358860 Value: 11
Address of num_p: 2358848 Value: 2358860
```

Output from debug, then debug_p:

```
Address of num: 2358816 Value: 11
Address of num_p: 2358816 Value 2358860
```

Comment: Use `%p` to print variable's address.

Comment: I gave you an answer, but I'm not sure if it covers your actual question. Could you rephrase it maybe? I'm willing to help you, but I don't see what your problem is.

Comment: My current problem is that I don't fully understand why the value of num_p in debug_p is not pointing to the address of num in debug, but does so just fine when done in main. Your answer clarifies, but it definitely isn't very intuitive.

Comment: Ok, I got you now. I'll give you another answer, because it's actually something different than what I have answered so far (which is still true though).

Comment: The `num` and `num_p` inside the functions are copies, passed by value, and not the same as the variables defined outside the function.

Comment: 1) when using an array, the name of the array degrades to the address of the array, so array, &array, and &array[0] all return the same address in memory.  2) the C language passes by value, not reference.  These values are placed on the stack by the caller.  Therefore, if the code takes the address of a passed parameter, it gets the stack address, not the original address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a variable to a function, you only pass the **value** of this variable. You never pass the address, because a **new** variable is created in that function. The parameters that you see in the signature of the function are all local variables, just like you would write them in the function body. These parameters are filled with the value that you pass when you call the function - but again, you are just passing the value to **new** variables.

```
void function(int a) { printf(a); }

int a = 5;
function(a);
```

In this example, there exist two distinct variables which have completely different addresses. They just have the same **value** (which is 5), but their addresses are very different.

The same happens in your debug function: `num` in there is not the same variable as `num` in `main`, they just have the same **value** (because you "gave" the value of `num` in `main` to `num` in `debug`), but not the same address. Now since `num_p` in `debug_p` still points to `num` in `main` and **not** to `num` in `debug`, the addresses are different.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `num` and `num_p` have the same address in both functions is because of how the stack works: The first call to `debug` allocates a variable on the stack. Then, when the function returns, the stack is freed again. Now you call `debug_p`, and therefore another variable is allocated. It will use the same place in memory as before, because the stack is built up in the same way.